# Can I put dynamic url in product description in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

In Magento there is an option to put dynamic urls inside certain parts of Magento admin panel.

Like this: {{media url="test"}}, it is supposed to resolve to http://example.com/media/test.

Is it possible to do this in product description field?

Comment: please read FAQ of this site before you post questions. You need to describe a little bit more what you are after in order others can understand you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do it is make your own block class, then add the following function to it

```
public function _toHtml()
{
  $processor = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_filter');
  return $processor->filter(parent::_toHtml());
}
```